# Print table format with dynamic column size

Tags: java, printing, format, formatter

I am not sure how to explain in words. I am trying to achieve this in my cmd after running.

```
Event                   Average     Stdev   Weight
Logins                  4.50        1.25    2
Total time online       287.15      42.12   1
Emails sent             65.40       30.71   1
Orders processed        150.73      20.13   1
Pizza's ordered online  2.03        1.06    0.5
```

But now my result is like this

```
Event              Average                Stdev               Weight
Logins                 3.33                 1.25                  2.0
Time Online               335.33                33.52                  1.0
Emails Sent                66.00                15.51                  1.0
Orders processed               150.67                17.25                  1.0
Pizza's Ordered                 2.33                 1.25                  0.5
```

The event name can be long or short, is up to user input. Is it possible to format nicely regardless of the event name length. My value are all correct, is just the formatting. Below is my printing code.

```
    Formatter formatter = new Formatter();
    System.out.println(formatter.format("%s %20s %20s %20s", "Event", "Average", "Stdev", "Weight"));
    int count = 0;
    for (Map.Entry<String, Double> entry : eventsMap.entrySet()) {
        formatter = new Formatter();
        String event = entry.getKey();
        double weight = entry.getValue();           
        System.out.println(formatter.format("%s %20s %20s %20s", event, average[count], stdev[count], weight));
        count++;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem is that you didn't specify the minimum length of the `event` string, therefore the subsequent contents positions depend on that.

But to avoid problems in the future I would suggest you to use fixed lengths, so if you have a string with length greater than the minimum length, the string gets automatically truncated but the alignments remains correct.

To specify a fixed length you should put both minimum and maximum length with the same value; you can also left align the strings with `-`.

For example `%-20.20s`:

`-` is to left align the string, otherwise it will be right aligned

`20` indicates the minimum length

`.20` indicates the maximum length, we put it equals to the minimum length to have a fixed length

In your example you need to decide the desired fixed lengths of all the elements you wanna display (also the `event` string) and then everything should be aligned accordingly.

If you want to be sure that the `event` string doesn't get truncated you could find its maximum length in your `Map` and then use that value to create the minimum or fixed length for the formatter:

```
int eventMaxLength = ... // assign the max length
String eventFormat = "%-" + eventMaxLength + "." + eventMaxLength + "s";
System.out.println(formatter.format(eventFormat + " %-20.20s %-20.20s ...
```

Comment: So i just need to find the max length for event length and change the %-20.20s accordingly right?

Comment: Yes, otherwise if you don't want to find the max length you can decide a fixed length and eventually the string get truncated but the alignments remain correct.